# On click event listener in jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick

I had write a simple code to delete a record on a table,

```
<td><a href = "#" class = "delete">Delete</a></td>

$('.delete').on('click', function() { 
     console.log('try');
});
```

The problem is that, If how many td's on the document I mean if there are 10 `td's` with delete class, it logs the `try` strign 10 times also.

Am I using `on click` event listener wrong or this is an issue on the jquery. Thank you.

Comment: Is that how its working or how you expect it to work?  The eventhandler should only be fired once for each element clicked (that has the class).  Don't assume, just test!

Comment: do you perhaps have your `.on()` call _inside_ the loop that creates each `<td>` ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code

Comment: there is nothing wrong there http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/37H7B/1/

Comment: Nope, If the user clicks only a delete link, then it will only log once. Not looping through all delete class and logs it ten times

Comment: I think you've mis-understood the jQuery selectors. The code you've written is doing exactly what it is expected to do. Perhaps you can tell us what is that you want to do in delete, we might be able to help you.

Comment: The `$('.delete').on('click')` evt handler is inside `on click` event handler also that appends dynamically a row if the user clicks it? But i cant seem to find a loop.

Comment: @Nesmar right - you've got an event re-registration problem then - even time you add a row you're re-adding the same click handler.

Comment: Thank you guys for your input. I had acquired new information in this simple question. I am not aware that I am doing the wrong way base on their inputs(the best way). Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single call to `.on()` will only ever result in a single event handler being launched.

IMHO, the most likely explanation for your fault is that you are actually calling `.on()` multiple times - perhaps inside the loop that's creating the `<td>` elements?

Within the single handler you can use DOM traversal to identify which column or element was clicked, and act accordingly.  If, for example, you wanted to delete the current row you could use this:

```
for (...) {
    // populate the table here
}

// handler will remove the row containing the clicked ".delete" link
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

**EDIT** based on new information from the OP, the problem is actually duplicate re-registration of the same handler over and over, each time a row is added.

In this case, the best solution is *event delegation*, where you put the handler on the *table* (just once), rather than on the individual elements:

```
$('#mytable').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    // do your delete stuff here
});
```

Note the additional `.delete` parameter to `.on` - this tells jQuery which particular elements within the table you're interested in - the clicked element will be passed as `this`.

You can make this call before the table is even populated, and it'll work on any `.delete` element found inside the table, even ones added later, dynamically.

Comment: +1 this is most likely the case and the solution seems nice. If the table is populated above it might also be beneficial to create the click handler _per element_ above (inside the for loop) rather than using a class name at all. If we use `$.each` or a `.forEach` loop (the latter in modern browsers) we can get pretty nice code here and create a scope for the elements and the backing data together which would allow us to separate concerns.

Comment: @Alnitak thank you, what information you had given is awesome. This solves the issue and the best way to do this kind of stuff.